# time.strftime() does not output time at beginning of code

Tags: python, time

I am using the following line to print the time at the start of my code.

```
print (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

I am also using the same command during long 'for' loops so that I can predict how long it will take my code to run. (I am doing heat flow modeling with a lot of time steps.)

The time at the start doesn't print until the first print time.strftime() command in the 'for' loop prints. Both are the correct times.

**How can I get it to print when the code starts, rather than when the next print command seems to flush it out?**

Comment: Show us your full script.

Comment: How are you running your script?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is to flush out the print buffer, which looks like this in Python 2:

```
import sys
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

In Python 3, it's even easier:

```
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I get different time in my for loop whenever i print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") I am using python 3.5

```
import time
print ('Started at :' + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

for x in range(5):
    print (x)
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('Current time is:' + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

print ('Script Ended at :' + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```